# mongodb with docker-compose [SocketTimeoutException]

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I have a spring-boot application running which accesses mongodb

When I use individual docker run commands, the application works perfectly fine. However, when I try to run all of them as a service, for some reason the application is never able to connect to mongo.

What I have tried:

- To begin with compose file [listed below]
- Run mongo separately and provide external_links to mongo [still
  fails]
- In the compose file, also mentioned depends_on [still fails]
- Override the hostname variable in compose file [fails]

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '2'
services:
 mongo:
  image: mongo:latest
  container_name: mongo
  ports:
   - "27017:27017"

 hygieia-api:
  image: hygieia-api:latest
  container_name: hygieia-api
  ports:
   - "8080:8080"
  volumes:
   - ./logs:/hygieia/logs
  links:
   - mongo:mongo
  environment:
    - JASYPT_ENCRYPTOR_PASSWORD=hygieiasecret
  depends_on:
   - mongo

 hygieia-ui:
  image: hygieia-ui:LATEST
  container_name: hygieia-ui
  ports:
   - "8088:80"
  links:
   - hygieia-api
```

compose file with external dependency:

mongo started with `docker run --name mongo -p 27017:27017 -d mongo`

```
version: '2'
services:

 hygieia-api:
  image: hygieia-api:latest
  container_name: hygieia-api
  ports:
   - "8080:8080"
  volumes:
   - ./logs:/hygieia/logs
  external_links:
   - mongo:mongo
  environment:
    - JASYPT_ENCRYPTOR_PASSWORD=hygieiasecret
    - SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_HOST=mongo
  depends_on:
   - mongo

 hygieia-ui:
  image: hygieia-ui:LATEST
  container_name: hygieia-ui
  ports:
   - "8088:80"
  links:
   - hygieia-api
```

In any of the cases listed above, the error I get is:

```
hygieia-api    | 2017-05-22 19:20:43,918 INFO  org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server 172.17.0.2:27017 hygieia-api    | com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket hygieia-api    |    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:63) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.0.2.jar!/:na] hygieia-api    |  at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:114) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.0.2.jar!/:na] hygieia-api    |     at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:127) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.0.2.jar!/:na] hygieia-api    |    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111] hygieia-api    | Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out hygieia-api    |     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111] hygieia-api    |   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_111] hygieia-api    |    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_111] hygieia-api    |     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_111] hygieia-api    |  at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_111] hygieia-api    |  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_111] hygieia-api   |     at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:50) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.0.2.jar!/:na] hygieia-api    |    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:58) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.0.2.jar!/:na] hygieia-api    |  ... 3 common frames omitted hygieia-api    | 2017-05-22 19:20:55,118 INFO  o.a.catalina.core.StandardService - Stopping service Tomcat hygieia-api    | 2017-05-22 19:20:55,127 WARN  o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase - The web application [api] appears to have started a thread named [cluster-ClusterId{value='592339f7e03dd80008647086', description='null'}-`172.17.0.2:27017`] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
```

docker inspect  gives the correct IP address the application is referring to:

```
    "Ports": {
        "27017/tcp": [
            {
                "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                "HostPort": "27017"
            }
        ]
    },
    "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/27e81b7954c9",
    "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
    "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
    "EndpointID": "ac2ded64c0bb0c9c1d82f4081b84ba2ae7f72e90527f310c7b107d0d3b7df1e0",
    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
    "IPv6Gateway": "",
    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
    "Networks": {
        "bridge": {
            "IPAMConfig": null,
            "Links": null,
            "Aliases": null,
            "NetworkID": "dc798dbca17eaced0a9bdb9f87da3672cdaa4424bafb0f49ba526c374cbfcc5b",
            "EndpointID": "ac2ded64c0bb0c9c1d82f4081b84ba2ae7f72e90527f310c7b107d0d3b7df1e0",
            "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02"
```

When the application and mongo is run independently it works as a charm

```
docker run --name mongo -p 27017:27017 -d mongo

docker run --name hygieia-api --link mongo:mongo -e "JASYPT_ENCRYPTOR_PASSWORD=hygieiasecret"    -p 8080:8080 -d hygieia-api:latest
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

When you're using docker compose **you may reach your container with the name of your service.** Therefore just change your spring application's mongodb IP configuration as follow:

```
mongo:27017
```

With your first compose file.

```
version: '2'
services:
 mongo:
  image: mongo:latest
  container_name: mongo
  ports:
   - "27017:27017"

 hygieia-api:
  image: hygieia-api:latest
  container_name: hygieia-api
  ports:
   - "8080:8080"
  volumes:
   - ./logs:/hygieia/logs
  links:
   - mongo:mongo
  environment:
    - JASYPT_ENCRYPTOR_PASSWORD=hygieiasecret
  depends_on:
   - mongo

 hygieia-ui:
  image: hygieia-ui:LATEST
  container_name: hygieia-ui
  ports:
   - "8088:80"
  links:
   - hygieia-api
```

Here's an example with **version: "3"

```
version: "3"
services:
    mongodb:
      image: mongo:3.2
      volumes:
       - ${HOME}/gocart_db:/data/db
      ports:
       - "27017:27017"

    blabla-service:
      image: blabla-service
      depends_on:
       - mongodb
```

In this example my blabla-service successfully connects `mongodb:27017`

Comment: Thanks! I tried that after posting and it still fails, it refers to the db as mongo:27017 then socket timeout

Comment: Also would you please try to put depends_on directive too, if it doesn't work I guess you need to create a network in your compose file which will be shared between your services.

Comment: Should we go through creating network though? Compose already creates a network. Cool, I'll try with version 3 and post the results back

Comment: I've added an example with the version:3 which works for me :)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks mate. Can you confirm it didn't work for in version 2?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm unable to test it with version2 right now, I'm glad your issue is fixed, please accept as an answer if it worked for you :)

Comment: Sorry :( it the same issue in version 3.

Comment: Strange, it's working for us. Could you please check logs of mongo with docker logs mongo command.

Comment: Also please make sure your spring boot application connects to mongo:27017 (check exception message there should be a hostname)